# Git & redirections

Tags: git

I've noticed that when a git (html) project page such as this:

```
https://github.com/fruux/sabre-dav
```

is cloned, in this manner:

```
git clone https://github.com/fruux/sabre-dav .
```

The actual resulting remote url, as listed with `git remote -v` is a url such as this:

```
origin  git@github.com:foo/sabre-dav.git
```

Presumably because I have push access.

So this made me wonder whether it's possible to redirect any given project url to a git repository. If I for instance own `http://myosproject.example.org`, is it possible to allow `git clone http://myosproject.example.org` and have it actually redirect somehow to a github project instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the bare git (the `.git` folder) is in the web servers `DocumentRoot`, and you set up a specific `post-update` hook, it will work.

[See this book chapter for more on this](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html#The-HTTP/S-Protocol)

To map your own domain name to a `github URL` , I think you just need to define an `A` record (if you know the IP address) or a `CNAME` record (if you only know the domain name) in your `DNS`

It may also be possible to configure a reverse proxy in your web server to pass the request for `http://my.domain.com/project` to `http://github.com/project`.

Answer (score 4):

> If I for instance own http://myosproject.example.org, is it possible to allow git clone http://myosproject.example.org and have it actually redirect somehow to a GitHub project instead

It could be possible in theory if the server knew somehow to redirect the url.
Git now (2.12, Q1 2017) treat `http-alternates` like redirects.

See [commit cb4d2d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb4d2d35c4622ec2513c1c352d30ff8f9f9cdb9e), [commit 50d3413](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50d3413740d1da599cdc0106e6e916741394cc98), [commit fcaa6e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcaa6e64b3f5eecde2b818385ec6f374f61ee7b2), [commit 6628eb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6628eb41db5189c0cdfdced6d8697e7c813c5f0f), [commit 986d7f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/986d7f4d37124e1ab7dcc99587f0d6d1deeedd9c) (06 Dec 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8a2882f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a2882f23ecce3a8742743555a408e508d4db806), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

> There is another way for a server to ask a git client to fetch arbitrary
> content: by having an http-alternates file (or a regular
> alternates file, which is used as a backup).
>
> - unless `http.followRedirects` is set to "always", we will not follow remote redirects from http-alternates (or alternates) at all
> - set `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS` alongside `CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS` restrict ourselves to a known-safe set and respect any user-provided whitelist.
> - mention alternate object stores on stderr so that the user is aware another source of objects may be involved.

---

Git 2.13 improves those http redirects by updating the base URL only if there is no error

See [commit 8e27391](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e27391a5fdc9194c4ed3ed6c64ec4750a1a08b5) (28 Feb 2017) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d0f549f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0f549f403266c14acc687098ee3e697a67984c2), 10 Mar 2017)</sup>

> [`http.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9d77b0405ce6b471cb5ce3a904368fc25e55643d/http.c) supports HTTP redirects of the form
>
> ```
>  http://foo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
>  -> http://anything
>  -> http://bar/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
> ```
>
> That is to say, as long as the Git part of the path and the query
> string is preserved in the final redirect destination, the intermediate
> steps can have any URL.
> However, if one of the intermediate steps results in an HTTP exception, a confusing "`unable to update url base from redirection`" message is printed instead of a Curl error message with the HTTP exception code.
>
> Teach `http` to check the HTTP status before attempting to check if only the "base" part of the URL differed.

---

But, as noted in [xpt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2125837/xpt)'s question "[`git clone` from redirect shorten url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116811/6309)":

> `git clone` should follow the redirect if `httpfollowRedirects` is not `false`.
> Actually, the URLs that end with `.git` give 301, as well as old URLs of repos that have been renamed.

So [301 ("Moved permanently")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), *not* [302 ("Found")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), used for instance by [git.io](https://git.io/) (even though [git.io is deprecated, starting Apr. 29th, 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-04-25-git-io-deprecation/)).

Comment: Hi VonC, where to set and how to use `http.followRedirects`? Say I have a  bit.ly  links to my github url, how should I specify that  `http.followRedirects`? I did `git config --global http.followRedirects true` before doing `git clone` but I'm still getting `repository not found`? thx!!

Comment: Oh, `git clone` is adding a trailing slash ('/`) to my bit.ly url. So I ask a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116169/git-clone-from-redirect-shorten-url instead.