# git clone from redirect shorten url

Tags: git, redirect

Following up from [Git & redirections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434605/git-redirections)

I want to shorten my super long github gist http clone url with bitly (or any other url shorter), but I'm always getting `repository not found`. Is there any workaround for it please?

Basically, I know I need to make use of `http.followRedirects`, for my  bit.ly  links to my github url.
I did `git config --global http.followRedirects true` before doing `git clone` but
I'm still getting `repository not found`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explored in the Reddit thread ["Does git-clone support http redirects?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/r5odvh/does_gitclone_support_http_redirects/) and the author found that [TinyURL](https://tinyurl.com/) works:

> My understanding is that `git clone` should follow the redirect if `httpfollowRedirects` is not false. Actually, the URLs that end with `.git` give 301, as well as old URLs of repos that have been renamed. Not sure why shortened URLs don't work then. Because they reply 302 rather than 301?
>
> Okay looks like it's indeed the case! I tried again with tinyurl which uses 301 instead 302 and it worked.
>
> Both bitly and git.io use 302. git.io is created specifically for github URLs but the URLs it creates don't work with git

Comment: WOW!!! I've tried many ways _on my own_ after asking it, and have _already give it up_, and you've just saved my day -- verified and it works like a charm!! Thanks a million!!!

Comment: Seems that there are issues with authentication though, if you use `https://user:pass@git.io/something` and it redirects, the username and password don't get send to the destination